Can I use spacy model licenced under CC BY-SA 4.0 Deed and don't change the license of my code?
I want to use korean spacy model, but it's licensed CC BY-SA 4.0 Deed, If I add this model to my binary file, will I have to license my code under CC BY-SA 4.0 Deed? (Important part of my program is not linked to this, model would be like a small feature)

There are different definitions of a model and depending on what you mean, different scenarios can be envisaged.
Please note that if you include CC-BY-SA, you can offer a binary based on CC-BY-SA without giving away the source code.
If by model you mean computer program code (specific implementation) - CC-BY-SA covers this case.
If you mean an algorithm as an idea, a procedure - it's usually not covered by copyright as long as you write your own interpretation.
As for the model weights that the program creates from the training data... the issue is controversial and it seems that model weights are not covered by copyright, but it is better to discuss this with a lawyer.
THIS IS NOT LEGAL ADVICE
